# Why queryset.only() is ignored when using serializers?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset, django-serializer

Could you give me a hand with this issue please?

I am using Django and REST Framework for my app.

I want to retrieve distinct values of 1 column in a django model, for that I use a queryset with chained filters and a serializer with the option many=True.

Here is my code:

Specified queryset:

```
queryset = CollectedCompaniesInfo.objects.all()
queryset = queryset.only('branch').distinct('branch')
```

Expected result:

```
[{
    "id": 16,
    "branch": "McDonald's"
},
{
    "id": 80,
    "branch": "Wendy's"
}]
```

I am getting:

```
[
{
    "id": 16,
    "branch": "McDonald's",
    "latitude": "35.94905003",
    "longitude": "-81.18771815",
    "state": "North Carolina",
    "address": "561 W Main Ave Taylorsville NC 28681 United States",
    "open_hours": "Mon-Sun 5 am - 11pm",
    "coordinate_x": 35.94905003,
    "coordinate_y": -81.18771815
},
{
    "id": 80,
    "branch": "Wendy's",
    "latitude": "35.24987478",
    "longitude": "-80.95769756",
    "state": "North Carolina",
    "address": "5501 Birmingham Pkwy Concourse A Charlotte NC 28208 United States",
    "open_hours": "Sun - Thu 6:30am -2am/Fri-Sat  6:30am -3am",
    "coordinate_x": 35.249874778495084,
    "coordinate_y": -80.95769756353488
}]
```

Viewset action code:

```
serializer = CollectedCompaniesInfoModelSerializer(queryset, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify which  `fields` should be included with `fields` and exculded with `exclude` as

```
class CollectedCompaniesInfoModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model =. CollectedCompaniesInfo
        fields = ('id', 'branch')
```

If you want to specify `id` and `branch` to specify only for read only then you can use `read_only_fields` as

```
class CollectedCompaniesInfoModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model =. CollectedCompaniesInfo
        fields = '__all__'
        read_only_fields = ('id', 'branch')
```

Comment: The problem with specifying fields in the serializer is when I want different fields when I do list and retrieve actions, I will obtain the same fields